# Jquery: $('<div>',{sort:x}) doesn't work; What is the 'sort' attribute for?

Tags: jquery, dom, attributes

When i trying to create `<div sort='xx'>`

by this function:

```
$('<div>',{sort:x})
```

jQuery ignore 'sort' parameter and get `<div>` only. When i make it by attribute setting fn:`.attr('sort','xxx')` is ok. Why it happens?

P/S: another attributes work's fine, is the reason why i changed ones to 'sorts', but what is the 'sort' attribute for? (i don't use jQueryUI)

Comment: which is the browser used? is it a cross browser behavior

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r59Nd/) demonstrating the problem

Comment: looks like the jQuey object has a method called sort... probably inherited from array.... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q28d8/1/

Comment: yes it is because of the sort method... inherited from array http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q28d8/3/

Comment: Arun P Johny,Andrew Whitaker,Thanks Gents! Actually it is!

Answer (score 1):

That's because jQuery check to see whether it has the method for the specified property or not, if it has the corresponding method, it calls that method with the specified value, otherwise it sets the value using `.attr()` method. In your case as it has the `sort` method it calls the function with the specified value and doesn't set the property using `.attr()` method.

```
// For internal use only.
// Behaves like an Array's method, not like a jQuery method.
push: push,
sort: arr.sort,
splice: arr.splice

// ...

// HANDLE: $(html, props)
if ( rsingleTag.test( match[1] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
    for ( match in context ) {
        // Properties of context are called as methods if possible
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( this[ match ] ) ) {
            this[ match ]( context[ match ] );

        // ...and otherwise set as attributes
        } else {
            this.attr( match, context[ match ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! now it's clear for me. .sort() is method of native JS array, this is why it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't work because there's no HTML attribute `sort`. jQuery probably goes through a list of valid HTML attributes, and only adds those in the list. Because of that, your sort attribute is ignored. If you want to store data within the div, you can set either the `data-sort` attribute, via:

```
$('<div>', {'data-sort':x});
```

or just set the data property via jQuery's `.data()` method, which doesn't require any attribute changes:

```
$('<div>').data('sort', x);
```

Comment: Doesn't explain the `sorts` case.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker "This probably doesn't work because there's no HTML attribute sort. jQuery probably goes through a list of valid HTML attributes, and only adds those in the list." (at the very start of this answer). So the explanation is that it's not a valid HTML attribute. What's still missing in that explanation?

Comment: `sorts` is not a valid HTML attribute either. Neither is `purple`, but that [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/r59Nd/1/). Therefore the reasoning that you need to specify a valid HTML attribute here is flawed.